# Running a new network request inside onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, multithreading

What is the best way to run a http request inside the `onPostExecute`?

The line I am trying to execute is:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imgData[i][0]).openStream());
```

However, it throws a `networkOnMainThreadException`, however I need it to run in the `onPostExecute` section. What is the best way of doing this?

I need it to access the UI on the main thread, as this is what the section looks like:

When an item is clicked on, you can see the code block where it adds an intent to it, it needs to access the main thread where it is originally created to launch the web browser.

Otherwise the error: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` pops up

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

   try {
       // set the URL of the image

       iv.setURL(imgData[i][1]);
       if (imgData[i][0] == null) {
            imgData[i][0] = "http://website..co.uk/images/url.jpg";
       }
       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imgData[i][0]).openStream());
       iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

       iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(iv.getURL()));
               startActivity(browserIntent);
          }
       });

      } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing your network calls in doInBackground()?

Comment: Why do you need to run it on onPostExecute?

Comment: No you don't want to run it in the `onPostExecute`. Maybe you want another `AsyncTask`, but definitely not `onPostExecute`

Comment: @KristyWelsh Basically, I download some JSON data in the `doInBackground()`, from this inside the string there is an image to be downloaded from the URL. I need the `decodeStream` to access the main thread so it can access the UI

Comment: @PedroOliveira Updated my op above

Comment: Instead of returning the json on your doInBackground() return the bitmaps, i.e., download the json, download the bitmaps and return them. On your onPostExecute set them on your UI as you like

Comment: @PedroOliveira yeah that's not a bad idea - I will give that a shot

Comment: @JoshBoothe for completeness: only iv.setImageBitmap has to be on the main thread. BitmapFactory.decodeStream you can do (and since you decode a stream from the Internet you have to do) on a worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Bitmap>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // code load the images ...

        List<Bitmap> result = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            try {
                // set the URL of the image
                iv.setURL(imgData[i][1]);
                if (imgData[i][0] == null) {
                    imgData[i][0] = "http://website..co.uk/images/url.jpg";
                }
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imgData[i][0]).openStream());
                result.add(bmp);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(iv.getURL()));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This will load the image in the background thread and set the image bitmap in the ui thread.